# Deleting a line from an input containing certain words without using a .txt file

Tags: python

Looking for a way to delete a line from input gathered from sys.stdin.readlines()

```
import sys
import re

userInput = sys.stdin.readlines()
        
TapeNumber = re.compile(r'[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d\d\d')

print(TapeNumber.findall(str(userInput)))
```

Following is the input

QE7951 Code Loaded   1412      Full
QE7953 Code Loaded   407       Partial

At the moment the code will take the input, look for the pattern and print out the results

I want to add code that deletes any lines that contain the word 'Full' before then looking for the patterns and printing the results

I looked and can see ways to do it by using a .txt file but was wondering if there's a way to do it from an input instead

Answer (score 0):

Didn’t test but should work.

```
Lines=[]
For line in userInput:
 if ‘Full’ not in line:
  lines.append(line)
```